# Need to insert - into a variable holding a date?

Tags: php, string

I have a date variable with the format

`2008 12 29`

to have it correctly display from within my database app I need the format to be

`2008-12-29`

Is there a way to simply add the `-` into the string or replace the spaces with `-`?

I am using PHP and the date is stored in `$release_date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$release_date = str_replace(' ', '-', $release_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) method is what you search for:

```
$good_format_date = str_replace(' ', '-', $date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that the spaces will always be standard (spacebar) spaces, use str_replace() as BoltClock said.

However, if it's possible that there may be extra spaces, tabs, or other whitespace characters in between your date parts, use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) as it will work in almost all cases unlike str_replace():

```
$release_date = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '-', $release_date );
```